# What is the runtime for initializing a hash table with n elements?

Tags: hash, hashtable

Is it O(n) or O(n logn)? I have n elements that I need to setup in a hash table, what is the worst-case and average runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Worst case is unlimited. You need to calculate hash codes and may have to compare elements, and the time for that is not limited.

Assuming that calculating hashes and comparing elements is constant time, for insertion the worst case is O (n^2). What saves you is the fact that the worst case would be exceedingly rare, assuming a halfway decent has function. Average time for a decent implementation is O (n).